# .htaccess to prevent hitbots URI "payday" and "loans"

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

One of my Drupal servers was recently hacked. Although it's clean now, I get lots of Google traffic for `/payday-loans` and `/leasehold-loans`
 and similar. They have generated enough traffic to slowdown my website and especially mysql. What is the correct code for .htaccess to redirect (or just stop) all URIs containing *payday* or *loans*? I'd like to handle these requests at the apache level--prior to PHP and mysql processing them.

Comment: Um, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this above any rewrite rules that you may already have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (?:payday|leasehold)-loans - [L,F]
```

This will return a 403 forbidden, but you may want to redirect to something else instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (?:payday|leasehold)-loans https://google.com/ [L,R=301]
```

This redirects any request with payday/leasehold-loans to google, or you can just 404 it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (?:payday|leasehold)-loans - [L,R=404]
```